# Retrofit 1.9 How to start new Activity from Callback

Tags: java, android, callback, retrofit

I have simply questions , I think is simply :)
I can't start new Activity from my CallBack method in Retrofit , I'm getting issue like

*" android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"*

```
    sign_in_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String userPassword = password.getText().toString();

            final LoginService loginService = RetrofitClient.createService(LoginService.class, userEmail, userPassword);
            loginService.basicLogin(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void success(User user, Response response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BetweenActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);





                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

This is my log:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.bunzlau.retrofit, PID: 18138
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bunzlau.retrofit/com.example.bunzlau.retrofit.BetweenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Button.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Button.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.bunzlau.retrofit.BetweenActivity.onCreate(BetweenActivity.java:18)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: It seems that your BetweenActivity.onCreate() is throwing the exception, so your issue might not be directly related to starting an activity from Retrofit.

Look for findViewById() in BetweenActivity.onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You're calling startActivity() from within the scope of Callback, rather than the scope of the activity. You'll need to get a reference to the current activity, and use that to start the next one.

```
private Context context = this;

sign_in_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
        String userPassword = password.getText().toString();

        final LoginService loginService = RetrofitClient.createService(LoginService.class, userEmail, userPassword);
        loginService.basicLogin(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(User user, Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BetweenActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);





            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for comment , but I'm still getting this error :"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException". Do you know maybe any reason ?

Comment: I mean , I'm getting reference  to the current activity , but it doesn't work correctly .